# how can check by console when a specific class is removed from my DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a class disabled in my code, but that class is removed from DOM when I refresh the page.

I have no idea how to check that and the Javascript is so big so I don't want to touch and break something.

So what is happening when I check my DOM I see:

```
class="btn-color rank"
```

On my HTML I inserted `disabled` class but always after load the page the 'disabled' class is removed.

```
class="btn-color rank disabled"
```

The funniest part is: If I insert a `div` bellow of that one with the class `disabled`, both will be have the class 'disabled'.

I want to know when the class `disabled` is removed from DOM. Does someone know how can I check that by console?

Comment: you want this only on page load right?

Comment: if you have JS modify a page, then reload the page, you load the ORIGINAL version of the page, with any JS-based mods destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the code of adding the disabled class. But you can do this as shown below in jQuery:

```
if (condition) // when gets the button the class disabled?
{
   $('.btn-color').addClass('disabled'); // add the class
   console.log('button disabled'); // log to console
}
```

You ask more than 1 question:

The code above adds to every button with class btn-color the class disabled. That's how it works. You can identify specific buttons by using the id attribute:

```
<button id="myButton">
```

And then in your jQuery:

```
if (condition)
{
   $('#myButton').addClass('disabled');
   console.log('class added');
}
```

Now, the class disabled only added to button with id myButton.